# Unity's free look camera too far away

Tags: unity, camera

I've been making a game to learn unity and I have been using the free look cam that comes default but have encountered a problem that I don't know how to fix. Basically the camera rig isn't following the target very well, it follows really far behind the target and I have turned up the move speed, messed with other settings but no luck.

Help please!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "FreeLookCameraRig" object you put into your hierarchy.

When you expand it, you will notice that it has a child object "Pivot" which has a child object "MainCamera" in it. You can control the relative positions of these objects to each other. Just move the camera closer to the pivot.

Alternatively, you can reduce the field of view of the camera. This is equivalent to a "sniper scope" zoom.